# Elastic searchquery by multiple value

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using java QueryBuilder to search values in elasticQuery.Below is my code snippet.
Sample 2 json store in elastic search
{
 "dataLayer":"sourcefeed"
}
{
"dataLayer":"sandbox"
}

```
BoolQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
qb.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("dataLayer",inputValue);
```

The input value can be either sourcefeed or sandbox or both,Depending on my input Value it should return the output.For single value it is working fine,But if I give input as InputValue="sourceFeed,sandbox" it is not working.Tried termsQuery also but it is not fetching correctly.Kindly help me to solve the problem.

Thanks Prakash

Answer (score 0):

```
SearchSourceBuilder query = new SearchSourceBuilder();
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
List<QueryBuilder> queryBuilders1 = new ArrayList<QueryBuilder>();
TermsQueryBuilder termsQuery = QueryBuilders.termsQuery("dataLayer.keyword", listOfValues);
queryBuilders1.add(termsQuery);
boolQueryBuilder.must(queryBuilders1.get(0));
query.query(boolQueryBuilder);
```

add sourceFeed and sandbox etc in one list and pass it in QueryBuilders.termsQuery.
Try this.Hope this will work.

Comment: (https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.elasticsearch.index.query.BoolQueryBuilder)
refer this